# How to measure task progress and update it using JProgressBar

Tags: java, jprogressbar

I want to display the percentage of the task completed. But since the length of the task depends on the amount of data there is to be read from a file I can not hard code the value for `pb3.setValue(...)` like I am doing it now. I know I can use `setIntermediate(true)` to display that the task is in progress, but is there any way of determining the exact task progress basing on the size of a file.

This is the operation that I am trying to measure, where `fileArray[2]` is a **text file** I select through the JFileChooser.

```
BufferedReader br3 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileArray[2]));
String line;

    while ((line = br3.readLine()) != null) {

        StringBuffer sb3 = new StringBuffer(br3.readLine());
            progress += 1;
            Thread.sleep(10);
            pb3.setValue(Math.min(progress, 100));
        sb3.reverse();
        bwr3.write(sb3.toString());
            txt3.append(sb3.toString());

    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: You could determine the number of lines in advance, but then you have to read the file twice. Or you could check the file size and update the progress depending on the number of already processed bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(fileArray[1]));

while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {

    StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer(
            br1.readLine());
    sb1.reverse();
    String lineReversed = sb1.toString();

    byte[] bytesRead = lineReversed.getBytes();

    for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead.length; i++) {
        totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead
                + bytesRead[i];
    }
}


BufferedReader br1n = new BufferedReader(
        new FileReader(fileArray[1]));

int totalBytesReadNow = 0;
int progress = 0;

while ((line = br1n.readLine()) != null) {

    StringBuffer sb1n = new StringBuffer(
            br1n.readLine());

    sb1n.reverse();

    String lineReversed = sb1n.toString();

    byte[] bytesReadNow = lineReversed.getBytes();

    for (int i = 0; i < bytesReadNow.length; i++) {
        totalBytesReadNow = totalBytesReadNow
                + bytesReadNow[i];

        if (totalBytesReadNow >= totalBytesRead * 0.01) {
            progress = progress + 1;
            totalBytesReadNow = 0;
        }

        pb2.setValue(Math.min(progress, 100));
    }

    bwr1.write(lineReversed + "\n");
    txt2.append(lineReversed);
    Thread.sleep(0, 1);

}

bwr1.flush();
bwr1.close();
br1n.close();
br1.close();
```